# Advanced WPF Validation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation, user-controls

Could anybody provide any link to tutorial which fully explains WPF validation.

I'm not interested in reviews, I'm interesting in MVVM-style validation using `IDataErrorInfo`.

There are a lot of simple samples on the internet, but I couldn't find any advanced sample, including nested validation in UserControls e.t.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CatelPart3.aspx#nested). Go through the topic in general to get an overall idea then go to section 4.2.3. which discuss validation in "Nested User Controls"

Answer (score 0):

Karl Shifflet has some validation examples [here](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/stuff-wpf-line-of-business-using-mvvm-video-tutorial/) and [here](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/category/ocean/). if you google "Sacha Barber wpf `IDataErrorInfo`" you will find very good documented examples.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx) is probably the oldest and most basic tutorial you will find on the internet. 
whereas [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx#validation) one is for validations on WPF `DataGrid`.

Let us know if you need anymore information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Angel, but of course I've already read this tutorial. I need more complex and advanced tutorial especially about nested controls and MVVM way

Comment: well for me even the most advanced validations begin with these tutorials. Probably if you ask the doubts as you face them, we can answer them better on demand.

Comment: The answer is in the end of the answer. In other words, how to organize validation in nested controls using MVVM pattern.